# SharedPreferences doesn´t retrieve Int value in different Activity

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

In my app I am storing integer and string data from different Fragments.
This data is succesfully retrieved in the same Fragment. 
The String data is succesfully retrieved over the whole application.

The Integer data however cannot be retrieved from different activities. In the same Fragment however it can be. If i try to get an integer from a different activity, it´s always giving me my set default value.
Here is my code. Note that i´m already using constants to retrieve data.

to save numbers:

```
public void saveNumberChange(String s, int data){
    String help = "com.example.test2.PREFERENCE_FILE_KEY_"+username;
    Context context = getActivity();
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(help, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt(s, data);
    editor.commit();
}
```

and get them back out:

```
public int getNumber(String s){
    int data;
    String help = "com.example.test2.PREFERENCE_FILE_KEY_"+username; 
    Context context = getActivity();
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(help, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    data = sharedPref.getInt(s, 0);
    return data;
}
```

The funny thing is, when i´m storing the integer as strings, they can again be retrieved in the same activity, not though from another activity. With pure strings everything is fine.

Some more code:

Save integer:

```
saveNumberChange(BeyouApplicationClass.AGE, valueage);
```

Get integer:

```
getNumber(BeyouApplicationClass.AGE);
```

Thanks for your help. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Are you sure `username` variable doesn't change in different activities?

Answer (score 0):

You cant access it from another activity because you are only saving it on that activity using the context of that activity.

**solution:**

instead of using the `context.getSharedPreferences` of the activity use the `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences` for your whole application to share data among its activity

**example:**

***saveNumberChange***

```
public void saveNumberChange(String s, int data){
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(s, data);
editor.commit();
}
```

***getNumber***

```
public int getNumber(String s){
int data;
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
data = sharedPref.getInt(s, 0);
return data;
}
```

Comment: this doesn´t make sense. why am i able to get strings from different activities then?

Comment: SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

Answer (score 0):

Try getting your preferences this way:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
```

in all activities, and getting the editor the same way

Answer (score 0):

So what i found out is following.

For everybody that has the same problem: 
Saving shared preferences from inside a fragment will lead to the problem i described earlier. 
Only that specific fragment will be able to get the information back out. 
So always save from fragment by calling its host activity. 
What i did is this:

```
public static void saveNumberChange(String s, int data){
            String help = "com.example.test2.PREFERENCE_FILE_KEY_"+username;
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(help, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putInt(s, data);
            editor.commit();
        }

      public static int getNumber(String s){
            int data;
            String help = "com.example.test2.PREFERENCE_FILE_KEY_"+username; 
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(help, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            data = sharedPref.getInt(s, 0);
            return data;
        }
```

make your method static so it can be called from within the attached fragment and everything works fine.